# Docker in docker connection error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a Java application in a docker container. The application also communicates with docker. So I used docker:latest image and installed the openjdk. Now when I am running the container in interactive mode (privileged) I get the error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`  when I input any docker command on the command line.

I run the container with `docker run --privileged -ti con_name`

Comment: How are you running the container?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/wiki/Docker-in-Docker) link? In there it's mentioned that /var/lib/docker needs to be a volume. In your docker run command, you are not mentioning any volumes. You might give this page a read and make sure everything is correct.